# Calculation of Hexagon Coordinates given row and column?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have the following example image of my hexagon "grid":

[image]

Each Hexagon has a column and row. The coordinate system I am choosing for my hex layout is an X,Y coordinate system, with the X coordinates landing across the red lines and the Y coordinates simply equal to the row. In my image I have the X,Y coordinate for each hex displayed in the middle in the middle of the hex.

**My Question**: Given the **row** and **column** of a hex, how do you calculate the X,Y coordinate of the hex (or more simply, how do you calculate the X coordinate, since the Y coord = row number)?

I have tried to come up with various equations that work for each hex but no luck yet. An equation that comes close is:

```
x = Math.floor(column/2) + (row%2)
```

But that doesn't satisfy all the hex's. I think I am on the right track.

Also, please assume that the hex grid continues infinitely down and to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if the sum of the row and column (i'm using matrix (row, column) = $(r,c)$ notation) is even, there is a hexagon but if it is odd, there is a common side of two adjacent hexagon.

The new coordinates of the  hexagon at $(r,c)$ is $$(x,y)=\left(\cfrac {r+c}{2}\ ,\  r\right) \ \ \  if \ \ \ \ \ r+c \ \ \  \text{ is even }$$

Comment: I'm confused with that syntax and how that helps me... I'm not trying to determine if a hex exists at a row/column or not. I'm trying to determine the x,y coordinate that that hex... In your equation, what does the comma and triple equal sign mean?

Comment: @Jakobud i edited it, you may understand it better now. tell me if you do.

Comment: @Jakobud $(r,c)$ is (row, column) and $x=\cfrac{r+c}{2}$.

Comment: `(r+c)/2`... geez how did I not see that? Thank you very much!