# Seeking a counterexample or proof to claim: "all regular polygons that can divided into triangles via straight lines can tile"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, recreational-mathematics, tiling

Inspired by reading up on [Tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) I'm wondering if there is a general proof or counterexample to the following claim:

> *Any [regular polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) that can be divided into triangles via straight lines  (i.e. without any change of angle within the shape<sup>1</sup>) will tile in the Euclidean plane*

My intuition tells me that the claim is true. But to formulate a formal proof presents a challenge for me, I presume it involves using [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) but I could be wrong.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>E.g. like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#/media/File:Regular_polygon_6_annotated.svg), but not like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#/media/File:Regular_polygon_5_annotated.svg)</sub>

Comment: What does "will tile" mean?

Comment: Every polygon can be split into triangles.  Do you mean equilateral triangles?

Comment: A pentagon does not tile the plane. Any polygon can be divided into triangles.

Comment: Editing! 7chara

Comment: Can anyone describe how to tile the plane using hexagons where describe means using discrete groups or algebra to get the veriicies

Comment: @StuartMN Think about the plane as being the field $\mathbb C$ of complex numbers. Add regular hexagons at the points $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ where $\omega$ is a primitive $6$th root of unity.

Comment: Thanks a lot N.S

Comment: @StuartMN This may also be useful to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247587/calculation-of-hexagon-coordinates-given-row-and-column

Comment: Among other things, the wording of the question is confusing. When one sees something in parentheses at the end of a sentence, after the words "will tile in the Euclidean plane," one expects that the remark in parentheses will say something about tiling the plane, _not_ that it will say something about something that was described much earlier in the sentence. Grammatically, your parentheses would fit in that sentence immediately after the words "straight lines." But even there it would still be a strange way of describing the kind of subdivision into triangles that you want.

Comment: @NS By Z[w] do you mean the 6 element multiplicative group generated by w describing one hexagon  or more probably the ring generated by Z and w in the complex plane but that would contain 1.2.3.4.5...which are not vertices  .Maybe the subtraction of one half w fixes that but I don't think so .I'm confused

Comment: @StuartMN Sorry you are right, ignore the second part of the comment. $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ is the lattice of periods viewed as a subring (I am pretty sure is the same as the $\mathbb Z$-submodule with basis $1, \omega$). But I was mistaken about getting the vertices faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your notion of using straight lines to divide a polygon into triangles is different from what most other people would mean by those words.

Here is a pentagon that has been divided into triangles by straight lines.

[image]

What you seem to want is a polygon that can be divided into triangles by
straight lines that intersect the polygon at its vertices
*and that pass through the center of the polygon.*

Among polygons with more than four sides, no regular polygon with an
odd number of sides can be subdivided in this way.
But every regular polygon with an even number of sides *can* be divided
into triangles by straight lines passing through two vertices and the
center of the polygon. For example, a regular octagon can be subdivided in this way.

But you cannot tile a plane with regular octagons.

Answer (score 3):

First, it is easy to show that every regular polygon can be divided in triangles, just connect the vertices with the center of the circumcircle.

**Claim** A regular $n$ polygon can tile the plane if and only if $n=3,4,6$.

**Proof:** If $n=3,4,6$ a tiling is trivial to find.

If $n \neq 3,4,6$ just calculate the angles of the $n$-gon and check that they are not divisors of $360$. This means that we cannot tile around any of the vertices of the $n$-gon.

Comment: note the edit I put

Comment: @PloniAlmoni I really don't understand your note. The first teselation changes the angles from 120 to 60, what do you mean by "doesn't change" ?

Comment: @PloniAlmoni Also note that no matter which restriction you add, my answer is relevant. If you ask "Can any regular $n$-gon with property $P$ tile the plane", my answer says that your question is just a fancy way to ask "Is every regular $n$-gon with property $P$ a triangle, square or hexagon?"